# How to remove curly braces before writing JSON object in java

Tags: java, json, maven

I am trying to make a simple JSON-DB in Java since the current library on maven is horrendously overcomplicated. I have this method that takes in a  key and value to put into a JSONObject and write it to my `database.json` file.

```
public static void put(String path, String key, Object[] value){
        //creates new JSONObject where data will be stored
        JSONObject jsondb = new JSONObject();

        try{
            //adds key and value to JSONObject
            jsondb.put(key, value);

        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //end try-catch

        try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(path, true))) {
            out.write(jsondb.toString());
            out.write(',');
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //end try-catch
    } //end put()
```

Here is my main method where I write some data to the file

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String path = "app.json";

        Object[] amogus = {"Hello", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Object[] amogus1 = {"Hello", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};

        JsonDB db = new JsonDB(path);

        db.put(path, "arr", amogus);
        db.put(path, "arr1", amogus1);

    }
```

What happens is that it save each data in a set of curly braces. So when I write to the file more than once like I do in my main method it saves it like this:

```
{"arr": ["Hello", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}{"arr1": ["Hello", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]}
```

This causes VSCode to throw an error since this isnt valid JSON. How would I make the method remove the curly braces and add commas to make the above JSON valid JSON? I cant seem to find the documentation for this library (The library is org.json on maven).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by reading all of the content in the file and appending the JSON object that I wanted to write to the file and then write it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax issue. Your `json` is not [valid](https://jsonlint.com/) because the `json` [syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_syntax.htm) want your data to be between curly braces like this:

```
{
    "arr": ["Hello", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "arr1": ["Hello", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
}
```

instead of this, which is not a valid `json`:

```
{"arr": ["Hello", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
{"arr1": ["Hello", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]}
```

Create your data in your map object and let your `json` [library](https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json) convert (serialize) your object in a valid `json`.

Comment: Thats the problem. The method is made to be called and write data to the JSON file as many times as the user wants. There's no point in creating a Map and hardcoding everything when it can be called as many times as someone wants in a program. Ths solution would be for it to end like your second example after calling for a second time seperatly.

Comment: @AlexStan0 the result you get is normal, because you write every new value at the en de of your file. You can pass a map in the constructor instead or use the `putOnce` method. Take a look at the Javadoc https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html